# Как выполнить фильтр по полю типа SET в Sphinx?

Tags: mysql, sphinx

В таблице есть поле типа SET. Пример `foo,bar,baz`. В одном из запросов для индекса у меня `JOIN` двух таблиц с `CONCAT` этого поля, что в результате приводит к такому результату `foo,bar,foo,baz`. То есть, в некоторых случаях, значения в поле могут дублироваться *(два раза `foo`)*.

**Задача:** отфильтровать результаты поиска по одному из значений для этого поля. Например, вывести все результаты в которых это поле содержит значение `foo`. Всегда выборка только по одному значению.

Все что я смог найти хоть чуть-чуть похожее на требуемое мне, это опция [sql_attr_multi](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current/conf-sql-attr-multi.html). Но я так и не смог понять как мне заставить ее работать, так как она ожидает `uint`, `bigint` или `timestamp` перечисленные через запятую, а у меня `string`. То есть ну ни как не состыковывается.

По идее можно было бы значение этого поля пропустить через `SPLIT -> CRC32 -> CONCAT` и уже это использовать в индексе. То есть получаются числовые хешсуммы перечисленные через запятую. Но MySQL не позволяет провернуть такое преобразование. Только через хранимые процедуры, а мне этот вариант крайне нежелателен.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение. Немного костыльное, но рабочее.

В запросе нужно перебрать все возможные значения для `SET`, выполнить для них `CRC32()` и `CONCAT()`.

Выглядит это примерно так

```sql
CONCAT(
    -- '0', -- нет необходимости прописывать ведущий ноль
    -- не смотря на то что в результате конкатенации строк,
    -- она может начинается с запятой, Sphinx проглатывает и так
    IF(
        FIND_IN_SET('foo', types) > 0, -- колонка содержит значение
        CRC32('foo'),
        ''
    ),
    ',',
    ... -- повторяем по аналогии для остальных значений SET
) AS types
```

Пример запроса

```
sql_query = \
    SELECT \
        id, \
        title, \
        text, \
        CONCAT( \
            IF(FIND_IN_SET('foo', types) > 0, CRC32('foo'), ''), \
            ',', \
            IF(FIND_IN_SET('bar', types) > 0, CRC32('bar'), ''), \
            ',', \
            IF(FIND_IN_SET('baz', types) > 0, CRC32('baz'), '') \
        ) AS types \
    FROM \
        news \
    WHERE \
        enabled = TRUE
```

и прописываем атрибут для поля

```
sql_attr_multi = uint types from field
```

В случае `JOIN` и объединения полей у нас в условие просто добавляется `AND`

```sql
CONCAT(
    IF(
        FIND_IN_SET('foo', a.types) > 0 AND FIND_IN_SET('foo', b.types) > 0,
        CRC32('foo'),
        ''
    ),
    ',',
    ...
) AS types
```

Проблема такого подхода в том, что запрос получается просто монструозный. Для одного из индексов у меня, и так не маленький запрос, разросся до 120 строк.

И вторая проблема, это конечно явное прописывание значений для `SET`. Любое изменение в `SET` требует правки запросов в конфиге Sphinx-а.

**PS:** `CRC32()` можно заменить на порядковый номер значения в `SET`, но я не советую так делать, так как можно нарушить целостность.